# what is the price of Pioneer P3DX

Tags: mobile-robot

I wanna know how much does  [Pioneer P3DX](http://mobilerobots.com/ResearchRobots/PioneerP3DX.aspx) cost? nothing mentioned in the website and I don't want to fill out the form regarding this matter.

Comment: This question seems off-topic for the site because the price may change over time.  Their website is the only objective source of information on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.seattletimes.nwsource.com/techtracks/2006/12/p3dx_robot_is_not_40k.html

According to this it is closer to 4000 dollars. If you are really interested just fill the form.I filled it out when they give me a price I will update this.

Comment: 4k? My goodness.

Comment: yes,This robot had a laser and many other top quality sensors